# Ruby: Count unique elements and their occurences in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a method in Ruby that takes an array, and counts all unique elements and their occurrences and passes them back as a hash?

For example

```
  ['A','A','A','A','B','B','C'].method
> {'A' => 4, 'B' => 2, 'C' => 1}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Note that since Ruby 2.7 the tally method does exactly this. https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
['A','A','A','A','B','B','C'].group_by{|e| e}.map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
```

Comment: @GreyCat A simple ruby question should by default be assuming the latest version. When older versions are used, special mentioning should be done. To you, does a TV mean a black and white, vacuum-tube operated one? Do I need to particularly say "color TV" to distinguish one from a black and white TV?

Answer (score 6):

This is the easiest readable for me:

```
src = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','C']
src.group_by(&:to_s).map { |a| [a[0], a[1].count] }.to_h
```

Or here is another solution with reduce method:

```
src.reduce({}) { |b, a| b.merge({a => (b[a] || 0) + 1}) }
```

Or:

```
src.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |b, a| b.merge({a => b[a] + 1}) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Following should do:

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
['A','A','A','A','B','B','C'].each { |name| counts[name] += 1 }
```

> counts
>    => {"A"=>4, "B"=>2, "C"=>1}

From comments, following one liner also do the same:

```
['A','A','A','A','B','B','C'].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |l, o| o[l] += 1 }
```

Comment: Or in one line `['A','A','A','A','B','B','C'].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |l, o| o[l] += 1 }`

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If you want one-liner solution, probably this one would be the shortest (albeit not most efficient):

```
src = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','C']
Hash[src.group_by { |x| x }.map { |k, v| [k, v.length] }]
```